# Ubuntu 14.04 for high performance computing cluster

Tags: server, cluster

hy guys ...I want to combine all the resources above 3 OpenStack my computer ? How to? Can anyone help me. 
so if pc1 = procesoor 2.4Ghz hdd=1TB 
pc2 = procesoor 3Ghz hdd=1TB 
pc3 = procesoor 3Ghz hdd=500GB

so my openstack have resource processor 8.4 Ghz dan HDD=2.5 TB 
can i using MAAS ?

Comment: Please read and learn.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes you can install OpenStack and MaaS on 3 computers. You will have to manually install it, as the automated script requires 7 computers in total. Otherwise, and you may have to anyways, you will have to build containers on each device. See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/en/Intro.html

Comment: yes .... i already have tryng install openstack on machine. but i want to tryng high performance cluster . i can use MaaS for that or no ?